# Integration with density functions, intergral in numerator?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, density-function

I have the following step during a proof:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFHZK.png

$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(y,z)}{F_Y(y)} dz \\
= \frac{\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}f(y,z) \,dz}{F_Y(y)}$$
where f(y,z) is the joint density function of the variables Y and Z.
F_Y(y) is the marginal density function of Y.
I dont understand why you can bring the integral inside the numerator. Then the denominator doesn't get integrated?
Tyvm for any help!

Comment: The denominator is constant with respect to $z$ so you can just factor it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F_Y(y)$ doesn't depend on $z$ so it's treated like a constant during the integration. The same way we can write:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} a f(x) \,dx = a \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\, dx$$
we can also write
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(y,z)}{F_Y(y)} dz =\frac{1}{F_Y(y)}\int_\mathbb{R}f(y,z) \,dz =  \frac{\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}f(y,z) \,dz}{F_Y(y)}$$

Comment: Oh, of course. good point. Thank you so much!